# datatables - sorting formatted numbers with dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, datatables

I am facing a Problem with sorting/ordering a special type of formatted numbers with https://datatables.net/. I have numbers like `111.111.111` or `46.323.345,88`  which are amounts of money.

I tried to use type: `num-fmt` but had no success. When i add this type attribute in my project i cant even sort anymore. Nothing happend like i hvae ordering disabled.

Hope you guys can help me!
ty

```
private initVolumenTable() {
    $('#volumen-table').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            {targets:3, type: 'num-fmt' }   
        ],
        "scrollY": "400px",
        "scrollCollapse": false,
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": true,           
    });
```

In JSFiddle the ordering happens, but its incorrect..

So i create one: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kn4s3ezg/2/)  . :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
      "numeric-comma-pre": function (a) {
          // prepare number
          a = +(a.replace(",", "."));
          a = (isNaN(a)) ? Number.MAX_VALUE : a;
          return a;
      },
      "numeric-comma-asc": function (a, b) {
          return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
      },
      "numeric-comma-desc": function (a, b) {
          return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give to DataTable the number with **common float** format, like 182948.847. After that, render your number with desired format:

```
$("#dataTableId").DataTable({
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: 3, // Place de column index here (0 to N)
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2, '') // Format number AFTER sorting
                    }
                ],
});
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/61407/how-to-apply-a-numeric-format-to-a-column